# Basic callback in Javascript

Tags: javascript, callback

How can I implement this code to run in correct order (A and B) without change the setTime using only callback?

```
function a() {
  setTimeout(function () {
    console.log('a');
  },1000);
}

function b() {
  console.log('b');
}

function c() {
  a();
  b();
}

c();
```

When run the c(), I need to run a() and b() in synchronous order, that's:

1. wait a sec;
2. run a() function...
3. ... and then, run b() function

Comment: Who do you mean by "without change the setTime using only callback?"?

Comment: That's *sequential*, not "synchronous". `setTimeout` is always asynchronous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mentioned using a callback - simply add an argument to `a()` that is a callback function that you will call after doing the `console.log(a)`, then when you call `a()` pass a reference to `b`:

```js
function a(callback) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    console.log('a');
    if (typeof callback === 'function')
      callback();
  },1000);
}

function b() {
  console.log('b');
}

a(b);   // note: no parentheses after b, i.e., a(b), *not* a(b())
a();    // note: a() still works without any argument
```

The test within `a()` to check that `callback` actually is a reference to a function means you can choose not to pass a callback and `a()` will still work.

Answer (score 1):

The asynchronous operation (what's being done in `setTimeout()`) would need a callback to invoke when it's finished.  Provide that callback to `a()`:

```
function a(callback) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    console.log('a');
    if (typeof callback === "function") { 
      callback();
    }
  },1000);
}
```

Then pass a reference to `b` for that callback:

```
function c() {
  a(b);
}
```

Comment: Great David. Thanks so much!